# Gatsby Site Requires Refresh to View New Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, service-worker

I have a blog run on Gatsby, and every time I push and deploy new blog posts I need to do a refresh on my page to see the new data.

I tried following the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225352/need-to-refresh-previously-vistied-gatsby-site-to-view-changes) and adding an onServiceWorkerUpdate function but that doesn't seem to have done anything.

Anyone have workarounds to this issue, and if so will there be a way to test locally? Changes already automatically update when I test in gatsby develop mode.

This is the entirety of my gatsby-browser.js file

```
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [`gatsby-plugin-offline`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/) first. Leaving your `gatsby-config.js` with something similar to:

```
{
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        ...
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-offline'
  ]
}
```

*Note: plugin's order matters in this case.*

The plugin will register a service worker and will load it into the client.

Then, in your `gatsby-browser.js` file you can simply add:

```
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    `This application has been updated. ` +
      `Reload to display the latest version?`
  )

  if (answer === true)  window.location.reload()
}
```

Additionally, you may want to add the following hack (very common across the repositories):

```
export const onRouteUpdate = () => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((reg) => {
    reg.update();
  });
};
```

Basically, it forces the registration of the service-worker across the site upon the `onServiceWorkerUpdateReady` refresh.

Check this interesting thread for further caveats and workarounds for some specific scenarios: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9087#issuecomment-774680408

Comment: got it thanks I'll give this a try after work!

Answer (score 0):

It will not work using Link provided by gatsby

```
import { Link as GatsbyLink } from 'gatsby';

<GatsbyLink to={to} {...props} />
```

It works using traditional a tag:

```
<a href={props.to} target="_blank">
   {props.children}
</a>
```